# Working with multi-threaded program but can not find created thread

Tags: ollydbg, thread, process

i am analyzing a piece of code in which the main thread does the following steps:

First, it calls CreateProcess() to create a a process in suspended state. Then it changes the starting address of the thread by using a combination of GetThreadContext & SetThreadContext. The new start address of the thread is now 00401E1D. And at the end, it calls ResumeThread() start the thread.

So, what I did was: I set a BP at ResumeThread(), let it run, after hitting the BP I step over the ResumeThread()-function and open the window where all threads are listed by clicking on the big "T"-button in Ollydbg.

But there is only the main thread, not the newly started thread. 
And now I have a couple of questions:

```
 1st question: Why it is not in the list ?

 2nd question: How can I find it?

 3th question: 
 In the main thread, I can not step to 00401E1D 
 (starting address of the new thread) because ollydbg somehow 
  terminates itself. Maybe there is some anti-debugging tricks or 
  things like that. I do not know, because I did not analyze it yet
  in detail. So, the question is: Is there a way to analyze the 
  new thread starting at 00401E1D in a separate ollydbg-session ?
  Is it possible ?
```

best regards,

Comment: The newly created thread is in another process - do you debug that one too? Also that technique is at least very similar to RunPE, so the usual techniques should apply.

Comment: No, I have not debugged the other process. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to creating the child process, `CreateProcess()` also causes the creation of the child process's primary thread. Your post makes it sound like the calls to `GetThreadContext()`, `SetThreadContext()`, and `ResumeThread()` all act on that primary thread.

> 1st question: Why it is not in the list ?

As you said in your post, you are seeing the process's main (primary) thread, on which the `*Thread*()` API functions above acted. No additional threads are created so you shouldn't expect to see additional threads in OllyDbg's view.

> 2nd question: How can I find it?

N/A

> Is there a way to analyze the new thread starting at 00401E1D in a separate ollydbg-session ?

Yes -- check the "Debug child processes" checkbox in OllyDbg's options:

[image: OllyDbg]

Comment: wow, what an answer. But which version of ollydbg do you use? I go to Options -> Debugging Options -> Events, but I have only the following options (see picture before your answer)

Comment: http://www.ollydbg.de/odbg201.zip

Comment: ollydbg 1,10 does not have  debug child process option if you want that options you can try using modified command line plugin (openrce downloads)

Comment: ok, thank you. But first, i will try to work with ollydbg v2.01. Now, I have the following problem: when i open the sample with ollydbg v2.01, then I get the following message: "Debugged application has modified the debugging registers. Maybe it called ZwContinue() or SetDebugContext(). The modifications are saved to the log." . What does that mean? how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: That's a separate question for a separate post. One question per post, please.

Comment: ok, I will make a new post.